# Why QWidget is not shown on QMainWindow?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

[image]

I am a newbie in QT. The problem may be silly, But it took my time.

In picture 1 what I designed, and in picture 2 what I got(when I run the Program). Why Menu and 'Click Me' button not shown on the window?
**Edited**

**Python Code**

````
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys
import os


from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = UI()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) ```
````

Comment: Probably your `.ui` file is not processed.

Comment: What if you maximize your window?

Comment: Try running QMake (Build->Run QMake) then recompile.

Comment: @Farshid616Does did not change anything.

Comment: Is the window with the menu and button launched when the program starts up, or does the program start with a different window?

Comment: @Carlton Program starts with a different window. In the launched window, I didn't see any menu or button.

Comment: It seems like you're launching a regular `QMainWindow` in your `main()` function rather than the `UI` subclass you created with the menu and button. Can you show your code in `main()` that launches the window?